# amdgpu-pro and rocm driver confusion

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I have an RX 5700 and wish to install the appropriate drivers for OpenCL support. [This article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ROCm-PAL-Future#:%7E:text=%2D%20ROCm%20generally%20can%20be%20faster,full%20HSA%2FROCm%20hardware%20support.) states that ROCm has a slight performance advantage and my GPU seems to be compatible with it. I will use my GPU for DaVinci Resolve and TensorFlow workflows.

What should I do?

- Should I install the amdgpu-pro driver and then ROCm separately?
- Should I install the amdgpu-pro drivers with the `--opencl=rocm` argument?
- Or should I use the `--opencl=pal`, legacy argument and install ROCm seperately?

Comment: I installed the rocm driver on Ubuntu 20.04 for its opencl support and the possibility to use tensorflow on rocm to implement a nn. It works good on hashcat as well (e.g with Hashmode: 22000 - WPA-PBKDF2-PMKID+EAPOL (Iterations: 4095) I got about 541.4 kH/s and with Hashmode: 0 - MD5 I got about 29456.2 MH/s - I have a Vega 64)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ROCm installation guide](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html), you should install amdgpu-pro or ROCm, but not both:

> **Note:** You must use either ROCm or the amdgpu-pro driver. Using both drivers will result in an installation error.